# Как обновить данные в MongoDB (Mongoose) с двойной вложенностью в express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Есть модель в которой свойство books с значением в качестве масива объектов(монгодб-документов). В объектах есть свойство notes с масивом объектов. Как мне обновить данные title и body в объектах масива notes.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    books: [{ 
        name: String, 
        notes: [{
            title: String, 
            body: String 
        }]
    }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Допустим есть роут для добавления note в определенной book по ее id:

```
router.post('/add_note/:bookId', async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
   await User.updateOne(
     {_id: req.user._id, "books._id": req.params.bookId},
     { "$push": {"books.$.notes": {title: req.body.title, body: req.body.body} } 
   })
   await res.setStatus(200)
 } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    next(e)
 } })
```

Как мне написать роут обновления тайтл и бади определенного ноут?
У меня что-то типо того:

```
router.post('/edit_note/:bookId/:noteId', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await User.updateOne(
      {_id: req.user._id, "books._id": req.params.bookId, "notes._id": req.params.noteId}, 
      { "$set": { "title": req.body.title, "body": req.body.body} }
    )
    await res.setStatus(200)
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
     next(e)
  } 
})
```

Ни как не могу найти и понять как обратится к такому вложенному объекту.

Может мне написать модель по другому или другой метод юзать, например model.findByIdAndUpdate().

Или может быть стоит написать отдельные схемы для books и notes, но тогда как?

Помогите плиз.